# Kotlin - How to implement AdMob ad as view type inside RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, admob

What's the correct way to implement AdMob ads (as a different view type) inside a Kotlin RecyclerView that contains an additional (but different) view type? I've not seen any helpful tutorials online. The issue I'm having is with the `onCreateViewHolder` method as I'm unsure of the correct way to modify it.

```
class AdapterMain(
    private val mCtx: Context,
    var myList: MutableList<ItemRV>
) : androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterMain
.MyViewHolder>() {
    private val myListFull = myList.toMutableList()
    private var mClickListener: ItemClickListener? = null

    private val itemRV = 1
    private val itemAD = 2

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return if (position % 5 == 0) {
            itemRV
        } else {
            itemAD
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) {
        return if (viewType == itemAD) {
            val adLoader = AdLoader.Builder(mCtx, "ca-app-pub-5544923106349792~1702536043")
                .forUnifiedNativeAd { ad : UnifiedNativeAd ->
                    // Show the ad.
                }
                .withAdListener(object : AdListener() {
                    override fun onAdFailedToLoad(errorCode: Int) {
                        // Handle the failure by logging, altering the UI, and so on.
                    }
                })
                .withNativeAdOptions(
                    NativeAdOptions.Builder()
                    .build())
                .build()

            adLoader.loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())
        } else {
            val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx)
            val v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rv_item, parent, false)
            return MyViewHolder(v)
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        if (position == itemAD){

        } else {
            val product = myList[holder.adapterPosition]
            holder.tvTitle.text = product.itemName
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return myList.size
    }

    inner class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    .ViewHolder(itemView), View.OnClickListener {
        var tvTitle: TextView = itemView.tv_title
    }

    interface ItemClickListener {
        fun onItemClick(view: View, position: Int)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is create 2 classes that extend `ViewHolder`; one for your normal content, and one for your ad view. You'll need to change some of your functions to use the generic `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` instead of your `MyViewHolder` as it could be either one.

In your `onCreateViewHolder`, you'll want to create one or the other, and return that.

And then in your `onBindViewHolder`, that's where you'll want to load/show your ad.

```
class AdapterMain(
    private val mCtx: Context,
    var myList: MutableList<ItemRV>
) : androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {
    private val myListFull = myList.toMutableList()
    private var mClickListener: ItemClickListener? = null

    private val itemRV = 1
    private val itemAD = 2

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return if (position % 5 == 0) {
            itemRV
        } else {
            itemAD
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) {

        // Create an ad view holder
        return if (viewType == itemAD) {
            val v = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx).inflate(R.layout.ad_item, parent, false)
            AdViewHolder(v)
        } else {
            val v = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx).inflate(R.layout.rv_item, parent, false)
            MyViewHolder(v)
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {


        when(holder) {
            // This is where you want to load/show the ad.
            is AdViewHolder -> {
                val adLoader = AdLoader.Builder(mCtx, "ca-app-pub-5544923106349792~1702536043")
                .forUnifiedNativeAd { ad : UnifiedNativeAd ->
                    // Show the ad.
                }
                .withAdListener(object : AdListener() {
                    override fun onAdFailedToLoad(errorCode: Int) {
                        // Handle the failure by logging, altering the UI, and so on.
                    }
                })
                .withNativeAdOptions(
                    NativeAdOptions.Builder()
                    .build())
                .build()

            adLoader.loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())
            }

            is MyViewHolder -> {
                val product = myList[holder.adapterPosition]
                holder.tvTitle.text = product.itemName
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return myList.size
    }

    inner class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    .ViewHolder(itemView), View.OnClickListener {
        var tvTitle: TextView = itemView.tv_title
    }

    inner class AdViewHolder(itemView: View) : androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    .ViewHolder(itemView), View.OnClickListener {
        // do any ad setup
    }

    interface ItemClickListener {
        fun onItemClick(view: View, position: Int)
    }
}
```

Comment: 'onBindViewHolder' overrides nothing.

Comment: @MacaronLover Make sure you update the class' generic class. `class AdapterMain(...) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() `

Comment: For some reason, my ad is not appearing at all (blank) but the space for it to go is appearing. Can you clarify if it's better to use the code below or the code in the `onBindViewHolder` method?

                `MobileAds.initialize(mCtx) {}
                mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView)
                val adRequest = AdRequest.Builder().build()
                mAdView.loadAd(adRequest)`

Comment: That code looks better. In your `onBindViewHolder`, that's when you want to tell things to display, for example loading an image from the network, or displaying an ad. I just don't have much experience with that specific ad library.

Comment: OK thanks. `findViewById` is inside `onBindViewHolder` but appears in red as  unresolved so do you know how I can get the layout (containing the view) so that I can use it to find the view? I know something needs to go before `findViewById(R.id.adView)` but I don't know what it is.

Comment: Thanks. I just realised last night. I still don't understand why my Ad appears blank. Google is so annoying.

Comment: Reading over the documentation for AdMob, it looks like you're doing it correctly. You want to call `mAdView.loadAd(...)` in your `onBindViewHolder`. Perhaps you haven't initialized it correctly? ` MobileAds.initialize` in your `Activity`.

Comment: That was already there but I've just noticed that it keeps replacing some of my `RecyclerView` items rather than being displayed as an individual item.